# How to open a URL in a user's default browser?

Tags: python, rest, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, webbrowser-control

python

I've tried using selenium webdriver, but you must specify the driver as a hardcoded browser type, and thus it doesn't support all possible browsers.

I've tried webbrowser.open_new(url), and although this works, I cannot find a way to RETRIEVE the REDIRECTED url which occurs after the authentication is completed in the url specified, and then to close the tab / window.

I need to:

- open a url in a new tab or window (ideally window) in the DEFAULT web browser of the user's system
- after authentication is completed in the url, the url will redirect to a new redirect uri
- I want to be able to RETRIEVE and SAVE this redirect uri + its additional query parameters
- and then I want to close the window / tab

When using the requests module:
I can't find a way to programmatically get the redirect url. For example (I can't find a way to programmatically get the redirect url. For example (requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/…), web application flow number 1. , they are asking for user input. Is there any way to not need any user input in order to get the url / auth code located within the redirected url? ), web application flow number 1. , they are asking for user input. Is there any way to not need any user input in order to get the url / auth code located within the redirected url?

Comment: you can use simple requests for this use case and get all information you need. https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, even using requests, I can't find a way to programmatically get the redirect url.

For example (https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#web-application-flow), web application flow number 1. , they are asking for user input. 

Is there any way to not need any user input in order to get the url / auth code located within the redirected url?

Comment: With requests you'll receive a Response object which contains an `url` attribute you can use. Also use the `history` attribute of the Response if you wanna check all Reponses in the redirection queue.
https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response

Comment: I get the Response [200] just fine. It's just that whenever I call for the response object's history, it returns a blank list, and when I call for the response object's url, it just returns back the base_url I input into the request object itself.

Comment: You gotta check if you are using the correct url. If you get a redirect - it will be in your response history.

Answer (score 1):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Use the `webbrowser` libary. You can use `webbrowser.open(link)` to open a link in the user's favorite browser.